# ServletFilter to get user information

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

i have database table for the requester information:

```
REQUESTER_TABLE(
  DATE DATE,
  IP VARCHAR,
  HOST_NAME VARCHAR,
  PORT VARCHAR,
  REMOTE_USER_NAME VARCHAR
)
```

I need to save user information once i receive the request from Servlet-Filter class, so how can i get the user_name of user regardless if he is logged in or not using the request information?

Comment: A request from an unauthenticated user, by definition, doesn't have a user name.

Comment: THANKS, SO I CANT GET THE USERNAME OF HIS MACHINE ??

Comment: No need to scream. And no, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look at:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser%28%29

You'll need also some kind of standard authentication:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncck/index.html

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnccb/index.html